# How to change credit cards on active subscriptions in Stripe while being SCA compliant (Intents API)?

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-sca

I have multiple active subscriptions that were set up by my customers using their credit cards  when signing up using intents API for SCA compliability.

Let's assume their cards expire and they want to change the default card they use on all their subscriptions. Until now this was done using the cards API by setting a default card on the customer account or simply updating all the existing subscriptions setting the card as default.

How does this work to be SCA compliant? Do I need to take my customers through a lengthy setup intent process on each of their running subscriptions individually? Or is there a way to create a single setup intent and assign that to all the running subscriptions they might have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [set the Customer's `invoice_settings.default_payment_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method) and that will apply to all of the Subscriptions they have - unless you've [explicitly set each Subscription's payment method](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-default_payment_method) (in which case you'll have to update each of those instead).

Comment: But how do I collect approval? Do I need to create a new blank setup intent beforehand (not attached to a subscription checkout process), have the customer authenticate it and then either update the customer account or update all the subscriptions?

Comment: You collect approval the same way you would have initially, by creating a new SetupIntent for the new card (and authenticating if necessary) and attach it to the Customer, and then set as the default as applicable.